# Is "annoyedly" a word?

Tags: word-choice, is-it-a-word

I want to say: "Michael annoyedly turned to face his brother."

I haven't found any solid evidence that the word "annoyedly" is an actual word, but I like the way it sounds for some reason. How *wrong* is it if I choose to use this word in writing I'd ideally like to have others read?

Comment: It is not wrong; adverbs can indeed be made from past participles.  However, at least to my ear, it sounds awkward.  I recommend recasting the sentence as *Annoyed, Michael turned to face his brother.*

Comment: What methods have you used to figure it out?  Dictionary searches, NGRAM, etc?

Comment: What’s a word, and what is the actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It largely depends upon what you mean by "actual word".

[Annoyedly plots on an NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=annoyedly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cannoyedly%3B%2Cc0) which means it's been used in books.

It does not come up in a search of most dictionaries.  It's not in my copy of the OED.  [The Free Dictionary redirects to annoy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/annoyedly).  [Vocabulary.com provides several examples of usage.](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/annoyed?family=annoyedly)

So, yes it's a word.  But, I don't know that it is a word that you would say has an accepted following.

Comment: To be honest, I had never heard of an NGRAM until now. It's very useful, thanks!